# Is it Possible to Use Both Video and Bitmaps?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I've been using SurfaceView and Canvas to draw Bitmaps to the screen. I've been looking into using videos to speed up some animation, but drawing Bitmaps and playing videos are two different things. Is it possible to draw both Bitmaps and videos to the screen? According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433525/videoview-on-top-of-surfaceview) it doesn't sound possible, but maybe there's another way?

Answer (score 0):

The last comment in there seems to indicate that he got it working. Instead of trying to layer a VideoView and your SurfaceView you are going to have to make yourself a MediaPlayer and set it up to play on a designated portion of the SurfaceView that you already have. VideoView is made up of a MediaPlayer and a SurfaceView, and you are disallowed from stacking two SurfaceViews.

That link to the [api demos in the last comment](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/MediaPlayerDemo_Video.html) from your question shows you how you "tie together" a SurfaceView and a MediaPlayer to make it show a video file.

Comment: Tried to copy what it does in that link, but I can't seem to get it to work.