# Draw overlay (HUD) on Android VideoView?

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview, rtsp, ondraw

I have a custom view that draws **HUD**:

[image: HUD]

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.widgets.HUD
            android:id="@+id/hud"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hud_fragment, container, false);

    frameLayout = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);

    hudWidget = (HUD) view.findViewById(R.id.hudWidget);

    videoView = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://88.150.210.138:5001/spor"));
    videoView.start();

    frameLayout.removeView(hudWidget);
    frameLayout.addView(hudWidget);
    hudWidget.bringToFront();

    return view;
}
```

I play an **RTSP** stream on my **VideoView** as soon as the video starts playing it looks like that:

[image: Video On HUD]

How can i force the HUD to draw on top of the **VideoView**? `HUD extends SurfaceView`

### Project

- ### The project I'm trying to add the the VideoView is [DroidPlanner](https://github.com/arthurbenemann/droidplanner) You can try cloning and see the problem. (Need to add the VideoView manually because it's not in the repo).

Comment: Have you tried `view.bringtoFront()` if your widget extends View . Your layout definition seems correct.

Comment: @Slartibartfast tried that, check my update. still the same.

Comment: I tried to recreate your issue but actually failed. Here is the project I made: 
https://github.com/andrask/androidhud It reproduces the same type of interface that you created with a video view a button and a custom view.  When the video starts, all the elements stay on top, nothing happens. The only difference is that it does not use fragments. Have you tried to use a single activity or statically linked fragment?

Comment: can you show me the result of : adb shell dumpsys SurfaceFlinger

Comment: @allprog My HUD view is SurfaceView maybe thats it ? And you need to change the folder name of your `com1` to `com` it causes Path problems for Git on Windows.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Mac and just tried to put together the test as fast as possible. I'll try to play a bit with your project

Comment: @Danpe I sent you a pull request with the working solution. It took quite a few hours to put together. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer for your question: [VideoView on top of SurfaceView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433525/videoview-on-top-of-surfaceview) The SurfaceView and the VideoView are both surface views and it was not supported to overlap these in old versions of Android but available since 2.0.

What you need to do:

1. set the pixelformat to TRANSPARENT in order to let the video shine through the interface

`hudWidget.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);`

2. set the HUD surface to be a Media Overlay.

`hudWidget.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);`

3. create a new surface and set that as the Display for a MediaPlayer that plays the video.

There is a pull request where you can try these. https://github.com/arthurbenemann/droidplanner/pull/247

The thread that brought the solution: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/android-developers/nDNQcceRnYA/ps9wTBfXIyEJ

Comment: Your answer looks good ! i tested it and I'm having problems, the stream gets stuck after 1-3 frames... Are you having this issue as well? or does it keeps playing on your side ?

Comment: Yeah, it sometimes happened to me too as the main thread got blocked too long. I'm happy it works now.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation on `FrameLayout` available here: [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)

> Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child
>   on top

Add an `id` to the `FrameLayout` in your layout file. In your `onCreate(Bundle)`, you will have something similar:

```
// find your framelayout
frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(....);

videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

hudView = (com.widgets.HUD) findViewById(R.id.hud);
```

After the video starts, do the following:

```
frameLayout.removeView(hudView);

frameLayout.addView(hudView);
```

Comment: Still nothing... I updated with a link to the original project.

Answer (score 1):

make a `Handler` which `invalidate` your `hudView` every 50 or 100 milliseconds

like this:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hud_fragment, container, false);

        frameLayout = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);

        hudWidget = (HUD) view.findViewById(R.id.hudWidget);

        videoView = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://88.150.210.138:5001/spor"));
        videoView.start();

        frameLayout.removeView(hudWidget);
        frameLayout.addView(hudWidget);
        hudWidget.bringToFront();

        //The Handler which invalidate your (hudWidget) every 50 milliseconds 

        new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
                super.handleMessage(msg);
                hudWidget.invalidate();
                sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 50);

            };
        }.sendEmptyMessage(0);

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Still nothing... I updated with a link to the original project.

Answer (score 0):

Test FrameLayout to replace RelativeLayout.

Maybe It works good.

Answer (score 0):

Extend `VideoView` and call `setWillNotDraw(false)` in its constructor. This way you can draw in `onDraw(Canvas)` then.