# Android: Is it possible to have two surfaceview on top of each other?

Tags: android, surfaceview

My idea is to have two surfaceViews. One surfaceView which will hold an image (say ImageSurgaceView) and second surface that lie on top of the first one which holds the annotations (say AnnotationSurfaceView) like circle, rectangle etc. Now I have to map these surface views such that the height, width are same and moreover, both the surface view should move on drag i.e share the touch events. To be precise, when I move the image up the annotations should also move up.

Now, I am not sure if this is possible in android. Can any one tell or share some info on this. I don't have any implementation idea to this and hence I don't have any specific code. Moreover, I couldn't find anything similar.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You can add both `SurfaceView`s as children of a `FrameLayout`. You will also want to call [setZOrderMediaOverlay](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html#setZOrderMediaOverlay%28boolean%29) on one or both of your `SufaceView`s in order to specify how they are layered.

Furthermore, this could be a graphic intensive algorithm you are describing. Consider adding the `AndroidManifest.xml` *application* attribute `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`.

Finally, just set up a custom `OnTouchListener` to handle drag events. Use `MotionEvent.getRawX()` and `MotionEvent.getRawY()` to get the touch point, and use this to manipulate the canvases.

Comment: I am unable to add both the surfaceviews to the framelayout. It says, I have to call **removeView()** before adding another child. Also, while setting the **android:HardwareEnabled="true"**, I am getting another error which says **error:No resource identifier found for attribute 'HardwareEnabled' in package 'android'**.

Comment: @Shobhit, the attribute was a typo, which I fixed. Try `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`. As for your first problem - this sounds like you are using a `ScrollView` instead. Can you add your layout (`XML` or programmatic) to the question?

Comment: hey Phil, there was a small bug and now I was able to get that working  but only partially. I have to still implement the custom OnTouchListener. Do you by any chance have any link to the example code? If yes, could you please share? I shall post the current code as my answer. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Shobhit, there are numerous examples on *StackOverflow*, but [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398057/android-move-a-view-on-touch-move-action-move) seems most promising.

Comment: I was successful in writing custom `onTouchListener`. I will post it as the answer below. But I would like to correct you at one place. `MotionEvent.getRawX/Y()` is automatically adding(atleast in my case) some extra digits to the exact touch points for example, the effective x is touchpoint+200 and the effective y is touchpoint+50. However, I used MotionEvent.getX/Y() which gives my the exact touch points. I am now able to get the touchpoints in both the surface views. I have to anyway expand the custom `onTouchListener` to accomplish my needs. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: One minor addition: setZOrderMediaOverlay() should be called in OnCreate() or it will have no effect